# Подзагрузка дополнительных дом элементов статического сайта

Tags: javascript, github, загрузка, jekyll

Как можно организовать подгрузку элементов как, например, это сделано в Инстаграме (добавление фоток при достижении скрола конца страницы):

[image: 123]

Розовым инспектор помечает элементы, которые только что были добавлены в дом.
Как такое сделать на статическом сайте (то есть без php), но через js? И можно ли вообще?

Comment: ajax запросом, который в ответе получает новые элементы, которые потом вставляются в DOM. Данные то откуда то брать надо (картинки), поэтому и ajax запрос. Если же вам надо просто добавить новые элементы при прокрутке - можно просто поставить на событие onscroll какое-то ограничение (например высоту окна или текущее положение скрола), при котором произойдет добавление элементов в DOM ( `$(".block").append("<div></div>")`)

Comment: @alexoander, спасибо, буду копать)